# #Recurrence T(n)=3T(n/3)+Ѳ(log₃n)

Tags: recurrence

Sorry I have tried a lot to solve this recurrence equation 
T (n) = 3T (n / 3) + Ѳ (log3n)
 with the replacement method but I can not get the required result:

1) T (n) = O (nlogn)

2) Induction
     Base: for every n = 1 -> 1log1 + 1 = 1 = T (1)

```
  Inductive step: T (k) = klogk + k for each k <n

 Use k = n / 3
```

T (n) = 3T (n / 3) + Ѳ (log₃n)

1) T (n) = O (nlogn)

2) Induction

```
 Base: for every n = 1 -> 1log1 + 1 = 1 = T (1)

  Inductive step: T (k) = klogk + k for each k <n

 Use k = n / 3
```

T (n) = 3T (n / 3) + Ѳ (log₃n)

= 3 [n / 3logn / 3 + n / 3] + (log₃n)

= nlogn / 3 + n + (log₃n)

= n(logn-log3) + n + (log₃n)

= nlogn-nlog3 + n + (log3n)

Comment: I said so because on the text of the exam with the solutions of exercises said that this was the solution so I do not know if the professor was wrong.  Anyway thanks for the help, because I did not know about this rule of the tetha where the 3 could be omitted.

Comment: Only one where did you take 1/2 and 1/4 in the part of the logarithm calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we can (eventually) ignore the base 3 in the Theta-notation, as it amounts to a multiplicative factor as is therefore irrelevant. Then we can try the following method:

---

*1. Hypothesis by inspection:*

If we re-substitute `T` into itself multiple times, we get:

[image]

What is the upper limit `m`? We need to assume that `T(n)` has a *stopping condition*, i.e. some value of `n` where it stops recursing. Assuming that it is `n = 1` (it really doesn't matter, as long as it's a constant much smaller than `n`). Continuing (and briefly restoring the base 3):

[image]

Surprisingly the answer is not `Ө(n log n)`.

---

*2. Induction base case*

We don't use induction to prove the *final* result, but the series result we deduced by inspecting the behaviour of the expansion.

For the base case `n / 3 = 1`, we have:

[image]

Which is consistent.

---

*3. Induction recurrence*

[image]

Again, consistent. Thus by induction the summation result is correct, and `T(n)` is indeed `Ө(n)`.

---

*4. Numerical tests:*

Just in case you still cannot believe that it is `Ө(n)`, here is a numerical test to prove the result.

Javascript code:

```
function T(n) {
   return n <= 1 ? 0 : 3*T(floor(n/3)) + log(n);
}
```

Results:

```
n           T(n)
--------------------------
10          5.598421959
100         66.33828212
1000        702.3597066
10000       6450.185742
100000      63745.45154
1000000     580674.1886
10000000    8924162.276
100000000   81068207.64
```

Graph:

[image]

The linear relationship is clear.